# Query Optimization - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a table of 3M rows.

I wanted to retrieve all those rows and do a visualization using `dc.js`.

Problem I have is, for just a single column it takes about 70 secs.

And If i write my query it takes about 240 secs to retrieve those rows.

I'm using using select query on columns like this.

```
SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM TABLE
```

That's it. No grouping, nothing.

But it takes hell lot of time.

Heard of indexing and I created a Index for the columns I use. But even though no fruitful results.

Comment: Exact PostgreSQL version? `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` ?

Comment: Version is `9.1`. And what's the buffers and analyze? I'm very new to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: Could well be that most of this "query time" is spent in your ORM or frontend, or sending the results back over the line. Try submitting the same query in psql to see where the time is spent.

Comment: I've got about 9 rows of result using the `EXPLAIN`. You want those results?

Comment: Retrieving 3 milion rows is going to take a lot of time no matter what. Are you sure you need all that?

Comment: You should include the exact query you are running, the table definition, and include the explain plan as Craig mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

We should not retrieve 3M rows in any query. And sending 3M records will always take a lot of time (nothing to do with the database, it is transfer speed). It will kill your IO. The bulk of the time taken is on the transfer (IO) from request-originator and the postgres database.

Consider to break that requests into batches of async-requests that gets streamed down to clients. That means restructuring your front-end code (javascript) for improved user-experience.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the environment in which you are using PostgreSQL.

As an example, in Node.js you can solve this problem by streaming the data with the help of [pg-query-stream](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-query-stream) and rendering it on the client side at the same time, so the client doesn't have to wait for the query to finish and can see intermediate results.

This may not be the best solution though. A better solution would be to implement data aggregation within a database function to provide a smaller data subset.